# How come no new lines are created in my IBOutlet label?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I wrote this code in my `viewDidLoad` function in my iOS project.

```
lettersLeftLabel.text = @"ABCDEFGH\nIJKLMNOP\nQRSTUVWX\nYZ";
```

`lettersLeftLabel` is a text label.

However, no newlines appear. Why?

Also, `lettersLeftLabel.text` apparently cannot be an integer either:

```
lettersLeftLabel.text = myIntegerValue;
```

fails too. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in `viewDidAppear` instead.

Of course you cannot assign a `int` to a `NSString*`. To do that you must do something like

```
lettersLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myIntegerValue];
```

Comment: Thank you, why viewDidAppear? I think it is working in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Because in `viewDidLoad` the view may not be on the screen yet, thus any assignment that affects the GUI is discarded...

Comment: @Saphrosit I think you're confusing `-viewDidLoad` with `-viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 3):

`UILabel`'s must have their numberOflines property set in order for newline escapes to take effect.  So this should work in your case:

```
lettersLeftLabel.numberOfLines=4;
```